# Code to perform cointegration test in Java

Tags: java, statistics

I am looking for a library or code to perform a cointegration test in Java between two timeseries. I know this exists in R but I would like a native solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go: [java cointegration](http://www.numericalmethod.com/javadoc/suanshu/com/numericalmethod/suanshu/stats/cointegration/CointegrationMLE.html)

Answer (score 1):

Although I haven't used it myself, [`JMulTi`](http://www.jmulti.de/) appears to provide cointegration tests. The Web site mentions Johansen test and something called the Saikkonen & Lütkepohl test. I see no mention of the Engle-Granger test though.

Comment: Thanks! I checked it out but it appears JMulti delegates to R or other non java statistic packages through JStatCom. Not sure though, will investigate more.